# Create TAP network device in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How can I create a TAP virtual network device in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

The TAP device acts as a bridge between the network and a piece of software.  Creating a TAP device is easy enough, but it won't do anything by itself - it needs some software to handle the data that's passed to the network interface.

Creating a TAP interface is detailed here: http://www.varsanofiev.com/inside/using_tuntap_under_windows.htm

There's a sample C program there to show how software to work with it can be created.